# Find string in txt file and get the following number

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11

I'm having an issue with my code, it is finding the string I want but it is returning the whole line. I want it to return just the part of the string I input and return the following number amount. As of now, it is finding "Tank 7000.99" rather than just "Tank" and it is not returning the following number of 7000.99. The info is located in a text file.

**Text File:**

```
Tank 7000.99
Cart 900.99
```

**Problem Area**

```
double getCost(string item) {      //string item = "Tank"
    string str;
    double cost;
    while (getline(file, item)) 
    {
        if (std::size_t pos = str.find(item))
        {
            cout << "Found " << item << endl;
            file >> cost;                      //file is the txt file
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Item not found in file" << endl;
            cost = 0;
        }
    }
    return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use `getline`. Just use `operator>>` to read the item. `getline` reads the whole line. `operator>>` will read just a token.
2. Don't read into `item`. Read into `str`. Then, you can compare the two.

```
double getCost(string item) {      //string item = "Tank"

   string str;
   double cost;

   while (file >> str) 
   {
      if ( str == item )
      {
         cout << "Found " << item << endl;
         file >> cost;                      //file is the txt file
         return cost;
      }
   }

   cout << "Item not found in file" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Suggestion for improvement**

I am assuming that you are going to call `getCost` many times in the program. If that assumption is true, the current strategy is going to be inefficient.

I suggest creating couple of functions. In the first function, read all the data and gather them in a map. In the second function, get the cost corresponding to an item with the map as an input.

```
void readData(std::string& file,
              std::map<std::string, double>& data)
{
   data.clear();
   std::ifstream file(filename);
   if (!file)
   {
      return;
   }

   std::string line;
   while ( getline(file, line) )
   {
      std::istringstream istr(line);
      std::string item;
      double cost;
      if ( istr >> item >> cost )
      {
         data[item] = cost;
      }
      else
      {
         std::cerr << "Unable to extract the data from line: " << line << std::endl;
      }
   }
}

double getCost(string item, // item = "Tank"
               std::map<std::string, double>& data)
{
   auto iter = data.find(item);
   if ( iter == data.end() )
   {
      cout << "Item not found in file" << endl;
      return 0;
   }

   return iter->second;
}
```

and use them as:

```
std::string filename = <the input file name>;
std::map<std::string, double> data;
readData(filename, data);
double cost = getCost("Tank", data);
```

Comment: Better answer than what I was going to give, but note that it does assume that it's ok for the "cost" to occur on the next line after whatever item was found. The main problem the original poster didn't seem to grasp is that getline() leaves the 'file' stream positioned at the end of that line, so if you wanted the value, you'd either have to parse it from the string you'd read the line into, or rewind the stream (not very efficient).

Comment: @R Sahu. This is for a programming class and we didn't go over how to use maps, so unfortunately I can't use that piece of code. However, your first piece of code works on the first try, but I run it again it will not find Tank. It tries to look through the file where it left off, rather than starting at the beginning again.

Comment: @WillEstes, that makes sense. To overcome that problem, call a function to reset `file` to point to the start of the file before every call to `getCost`. That call is `file.seekg(0);`.